# To what extent is Linux prevalent in University maths departments?

Tags: mathematics, university

To what extent is Linux prevelant in University maths departments? I understand that distributions such as Scientific Linux and Fedora are quite popular, but I don't know whether this means 5% or 50% uptake. Is Linux the most common operating system in the world of maths academia, or is it still a minority player? If you were to estimate a percentage of maths academics who use Linux, what number would you suggest?

Comment: The last sentence makes this question sound like a poll - that would be off-topic.

Comment: It's not a poll because it's not asking for an opinion, it's asking for a best guess at a fact. I want to find the closest thing to a true value, while accepting that there is likely no good way to achieve that beyond asking for the gut feeling of people in academia.

Comment: Agree it's not a poll, but answers may be all over the place because of differences by sub-field and by countries. From my (physics) experience, things vary widely based on those two degrees of freedom. So, I suggest you specify your subfield(s) and region(s) of interest.

Comment: Best guess at fact like this is still a poll, unless you're asking if anyone did actual research into the subject.

Comment: Is there a question behind the question, like a purpose for which you'll use the answer? Are you looking to avoid Linux, or are you looking specifically _for_ Linux, or is there another reason for the question? As the question stands, it's sort of a poll or a request for statistics, which isn't as useful as a question that presents a problem to be solved. Any [edit]s to steer it in the direction of a problem would be helpful.

Comment: @shoover in its original intent the question was a request for statistics. Would it be a more suitable fit for this community if I broadened it to ask something closer to:

"On what basis do mathematics faculties favour particular operating systems over others, and what operating systems tend to be favoured?"

Answer (score 1):

In Germany, Linux is pretty common as end user operating system in maths departments. I worked at three different universities in Germany and they all used it.

On the other hand, many people use their private laptops for work (when they are at home or travel), and I guess (but don't know) that Linux is not so dominant there.